# Where i should put dynamic and reactive parameter - in vue computed or vue store?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

**DISCLAIMER**

I have vuex store, that **store** some data. For example -> shops and topCategories 
In topCategories i have dict with top products in a shop like this

`{ '1' : 
     {name: 'Banana', category: 'Fruits', 'sales': 50}, 
     {name: 'Apple', category: 'Fruits', 'sales': 50}
 }` where '1' is shopID

And for each shop we have the same topProducts dict structure.

I have a component that display topProducts for selected shop and component should display top products without duplicates. He should sum up if names of products equal.

**QUESTION**
Where i should put this logic? In 'computed' in view component or in vuex store action?

Comment: *He should sum up if names of products equal* do you mean that in your store you have sometimes entries like `{'1': {name:'Apple', ...}, {name:'Apple', ...}}`?

Comment: @BillalBegueradj yes!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to store the data in vuex and then access the getters in the computed method:

```
computed: {
  ...mapGetters(['topProducts'])
}
```

In your getters:

```
topProducts: state => state.topProducts
```

To sum up, you'll need an action that will commit the mutation. Or even you can use the getters. Here's an example:

```
computed: {
   ...mapGetters([
     'summingA',
     'summingB'
   ]),
   getTotal() {
    return this.summingA + this.summingB
   }
}
```

In your getters:

```
summingA: state => state.summingA,
summingB: state => state.summingB
```

Comment: I know it. I asked about sum up logic

Comment: Updated my answer. Hope, this helps now.

Answer (score 0):

In my humble opinion you should re-think a little bit more about how you designed this aspect so far. I mean you should not be in a scenario where your store contains duplicate data like this:

```
{ '1' : 
     {name: 'Apple', category: 'Fruits', 'sales': 50}, 
     {name: 'Apple', category: 'Fruits', 'sales': 50}
}
```

By [principle](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/state.html) the store serves as the single source of truth which makes it straightforward to locate a specific piece of state. This implicitly means it is not a good design to have duplicate entries within the store's state. You should store the data before saving it into the store. Complying to  this design principle would prevent you from dealing with questions like that one.

Comment: Looks like i ask my question very bad. I have those dicts for all shops by id and when i select shop 1 and shop 2 view component should display those dicts without duplicates and summed if it have equal names